# Symfony 3.4 located in subdirecory, remove web/ from url

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I have 3 php apps on one server. I cant modify any apache files. Haw can I set .htaccess to remove web/ folder from url?

```
192.168.45.54/app1/
192.168.45.54/app2/
192.168.45.54/app3/web - I want to change it to 192.168.45.54/app3/
```

On adress 192.168.45.54/app3/web/ everythink is working fine. But haw can I remove web/ from url?

I created .htaccess files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But when I go to 192.168.45.54/app3/ in symfony log files I have fallowing error:

```
No route found for "GET /app3/"
```

I use Symfony in 3.4 version. I think that problem is in .htaccess located in /web directory... Haw to configure .htaccess corectly?

I can't create virtual host becouse I haven't access to the server...

Comment: Maybe you can just symlink it?

Comment: This is a solution but I need to understand how to make it by .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `web/` directory the document root of your website. If you have direct access to the webserver’s virtual host configuration, change the document root to the following line and restart Apache:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/symfony/web/
```

If you can’t modify the virtual host file directly, your hosting provider will usually give you the possibility to modify the document root through some kind of online tool.

Comment: I know about DocumentRoot and apache configuration. I do not have access to part of the server because the data on it are protected - company policy... and I can't change root directory for my website becouse on the same host/domain are working another applications like: 192.168.45.54/app1/; 192.168.45.54/app2/; 192.168.45.54/app3/; - this is not my idea 
and I'm not a decision-maker to change it. So, it is possible to create .htaccess like I described in my first post?

Comment: Would you be able to install the Symfony application one level below the current document root and put the content of the `web/` directory into the document root?

Comment: unfortunately I do not have access to directories below 192.168.45.54/app3/